# How to provide a counterexample for if $n$ is prime, then $2^n -1$ is prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I have the following question where I need to provide a **counterexample**

> if $n$ is prime, then $2^n -1$ is prime

The statement is invalid and I now that $2^n -1$ is not prime when $ n = 11$, but other than plugging in prime numbers is there any other way to figure out whether $2^n -1$ is prime if $n$ is prime?

Comment: Is the only way to provide a counterexample by plugging in numbers or is there some other way that would be more efficient?

Comment: Simple answer: No there isn't. This is a kind of prime called a Mersenne prime, and, trust me, if we knew a better way then that would make finding huge primes easy.

Comment: The Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search ([www.mersenne.org](https://www.mersenne.org/), [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Internet_Mersenne_Prime_Search)) has been testing these numbers for more than 22 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's [a way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) to test for prime $n$ whether $2^n-1$ is prime without computing it first, but showing some $n$ fails *that* test still requires manually finding a counterexample. A proof that didn't have this requirement would be nonconstructive; but I doubt there's a nonconstructive proof not all prime $n$ obtain prime $2^n-1$.